# Laravel Where Issue, Maybe with Pagination?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having an issue here where something works just fine on the first 10 results, but when I click on the second pagination, or if I perform a sort that brings the record in question into display, it causes an issue. It basically is a where request to display another record on the same table, and it works with the other records.

I have created different records where they work fine if they are in the first 10 results, but the moment I change them to appear after the pagination break, I get this same error. Otherwise, it works fine if the field is null.

The error it is giving me is that it appears as a non-object, but the code works with every other similar record with the same object selected.

**Error**

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property 'full_name' of non-object (View: resources/views/doctors/index.blade.php)

<td><?php echo e($doctors->where('id', $doctor->ffs_id)->first()->full_name); ?></td>
```

**Code**

```
@if ($doctor->ffs_id == null)
    <td></td>
@else
    <td>
        {{ $doctors->where('id', $doctor->ffs_id)->first()->full_name }}
    </td>
@endif
```

**Pagination Code: Blade**

```
{{ $doctors->appends([
    'search' => $search,
    'sortColumn' => $sortColumn,
    'sortDirection' => $sortDirection
])->links() }}
```

**Pagination Code: Controller**

```
// Searches, sorts, and filters
$approved = $request->approved;
$search = $request->search;
$sortColumn = ($request->sortColumn == null ? 'last_name' : $request->sortColumn);
$sortDirection = ($request->sortDirection == null ? 'asc' : $request->sortDirection);

$doctors = Doctor::
    when($search, function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query
                ->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('type', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('npi', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('license', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('dea', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
        });
    })
    ->when($approved, function ($query) use ($approved) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($approved) {
            $query->where('is_approved', $approved);
        });
    })
    ->orderBy($sortColumn, $sortDirection)
    ->paginate(10);
```

**Edit:** Even removing all of the sort functionality and attempting a load of `/doctors?page=2` gives the same error.

**Edit 2:** I've confirmed that it has something to do with how `$doctors` is written in the controller. If I create a version of `Doctor::all()` and reference it in the blade, it pulls up with no errors.

Comment: Likely means that `$doctors->where('id', $doctor->ffs_id)->first()` is returning `null`; Are you sure there is a `Doctor` with an `id` of `$doctor->ffs_id`? Also, if you already have `$doctor`, why do you need to filter `$doctors` to find that? Wouldn't `$doctors->where('id', $doctor->ffs_id)->first()` theoretically return the same thing that's already in `$doctor`? Couldn't you just do `$doctor->full_name`?

Comment: The `ffs_id` column on a doctor's record references the `id` of another doctor on the doctors table. So I used `$doctors->where('id', $doctor->ffs_id)->first()->full_name` to find the referenced FFS doctor of the $doctor in question. And I don't know why the where statement would return null if it's not returning null when it's on a different page or with no changes to any of the other records on the front page and displaying correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're searching for the parent Doctor record within the original Collection of `$doctors` returned by the pagination query. If the parent Doctor isn't in the current page of records, your "query" result will be null.

**The problem:** You have 100 Doctors, with IDs #1-100. You're fetching the first page, so `$doctors` will contain Doctors #1-10. (Simple example with no searching or anything, just standard pagination.)

Doctor #2 has an `ffs_id` value of `39`. Because you're searching the `$doctors` collection for a Doctor with ID #39, it won't be found, because `$doctors` only contains #1-10.

So, you're 100% correct in that the issue is with the contents of `$doctors`.

**Solution:** Create an Eloquent relationship method for this Doctor-to-Doctor relationship. Something like this (adjusted to your app's needs):

```
public function ffs()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Doctor::class);
}
```

Use this relationship to retrieve and reference the parent Doctor within your results (bonus sugar here using [`optional`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-optional) to remove the `@if` check from the view):

```
<td>
    {{ optional($doctor->ffs)->full_name }}
</td>
```

This will directly query the database for the related record, instead of using the `$doctors` collection.

At this point, we'll run into something called [the N+1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-object-relational-mapping), where every parent Doctor request will be an individual database query. You can fix this using one of the [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) methods.